# Primary Exchange 2003 calendar not syncing with iPhone, while other calendars do

Tags: exchange-2003, iphone

I have an issue with a user where their *primary* Exchange calendar is not syncing with their iPhone. They have another calendar (personal events) in their profile that is syncing correctly.

So far, I've tried restarting all Exchange services on the server and I tried deleting the iPhone exchange profile and re-adding it. Neither step yielded any results. I also attempted creating a third calendar with some dummy events, which **did sync** properly to the iPhone.

I also confirmed that the calendar in question does indeed have events by deleting offline content in Outlook and re-syncing the events from the server.

What could be causing this, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: How large is the user's mailbox?

Comment: @CIA Huge, but email is not affected. And it was working as of ~2 weeks ago, with no significant changes made to their mailbox/size. Currently their store is ~30GB

Comment: Mailbox size affects just about everything in Exchange 2003.  Can you test the calendar with a test account that has a empty mailbox? Do you have a cluster environment in place or just a single server? Also, do you have ActiveSync logging enabled?  Can you pull anything from the logs that relate to the user in question?

Comment: I'll attempt your first suggestion. This is just a single server with frontend. I'm not sure about activesync logging but I'll check.

Comment: @Moses, you are assuming that it's a problem with exchange, but have you already checked the client side? Just a thought...may have look here: (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203521)

Comment: Any update with using a test account?

Comment: I was able to get 2 test accounts working properly: one that already exists (another user's profile) and an empty one with some dummy items in the calendar.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen email accounts stop syncing on both Android and the iPhone 5. Deleting the account on the phone and adding it again does often correct the issue for us.

However, since you have already tried this, verify that the mail days to sync is set to something reasonable like 1 week. I have seen strange issues when our users attempt to get all of their mail onto their phone.

Once that is set, turn off WiFi and see if the account will sync on 4G. After the initial sync, turn on WiFi and send them another test email.

On the apple discussion boards, one user said that they had to perform the following steps (in order):

Delete the iphone account for exchange

```
Settings -> Mail, Contacts, Calendars -> Exchange account -> Delete Account
```

Reset Network Settings

```
Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Network Settings
```

The phone will reboot.

After the phone reboots, don't add any WiFi networks, until after the exchange account is set up again

```
Settings -> Mail, Contacts, Calendars -> Add Account
```

Fill in all settings and ensure all have √ marks

If email syncs, add a WiFi connection and enable it, then send a test email to see if email is delivered and sync'd properly.

Comment: The issue isn't with mail - only with one particular calendar.

Comment: Either way, these steps did not resolve the problem with the one calendar not syncing.